# Firefox extension with server socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox, firefox-addon, read-eval-print-loop

I need to write an extension for firefox that accepts data from a socket connection and can send reply messages via the same port. I was wondering if anyone knows of any tutorials or some example code I can look at for accomplishing this as I cannot find very many guides for Firefox 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can use the nsIServerSocket interface from mozilla.org in javascript to create a socket connection and read in and print out into streams associated with that connection.

Comment: After a little research I was able to find the answer thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using beta 8+, it may be disabled due to security issues.

[See here](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/biz-enterprise/388561-websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4)

If you want a socket library that falls back to Flash and then long polling, check out [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

Comment: i managed to get one working using mozilla's nsIServerSocket, it's just that I've been struggling to get it working with the new changes to xpcom. I'm using 4.0b8 and it works just fine.